# from transformers import TFBertModel, BertConfig, BertTokenizerFast

Tags: bert-language-model

I am having trouble importing TFBertModel,  BertConfig, BertTokenizerFast. I tried the latest version of transformers, tokenizer==0.7.0, and transformers.modeling_bert but they do not seem to work. I get the error

`from transformers import TFBertModel,  BertConfig, BertTokenizerFast`

ImportError: cannot import name 'TFBertModel' from 'transformers' (unknown location)

Any ideas for a fix? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `Tensorflow 2` installed? The model you are trying to import required Tensorflow